# Why do higher order finite elements (Q2) do not perform well for large Peclet number flows, as compared to Q1 finite elments?

Tags: finite-element, linear-solver

I a solving the 2d steady state convection-diffusion problem on the famous flow around a cylinder in rectangular domain benchmark. My numerical results show that with Q1 finite elements, the solver is converging for Pe=5000, whereas with Q2  discretization, the solver fails to converge. What can be the reason for poor performance in case of Q2 FEM discretization?

Comment: How are you stabilizing the equations in the high-Pe case?

Comment: @ Wolfgang Bangerth I am using edge-oriented jump stabilization, the solver is now converging for the Q2 case, but still, performance of solver is not as good as that for Q1 case